# Filter fails if a column is blank

Tags: excel, vba

Data is filter based on criteria in Col C. 
`copyRng.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"`

Filter data is copied to another sheet.  It works perfectly when there is at least one cell with data in that column but if the whole column is blank it copies all of the rows, however, it shouldn’t copy anything.  What can be done fix this problem? Thank you

```
    Public Sub CopyCLMData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim maxCell As Range
    Dim lRowAccess As Long
    Dim lRowThisWS As Long
    Dim lColThisWS As Long
    Dim copyRng As Range, copyRng2 As Range
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim startCol As Long

    Dim maxXLRows As Long

    startRow = 2
    startCol = 1

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'copy header row
    wsAll.Rows(1).Copy
    wsAccess.Rows(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'get summary counts only once (outside of the loop)
    maxXLRows = wsAccess.Rows.Count     'total rows available in summary sheet

    'Copy Colon, Lung, and Melanoma data to summary worksheet (Access)
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.name = WS_COLON Or ws.name = WS_LUNG Or ws.name = WS_MELA Then

            lRowThisWS = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            Debug.Print lRowThisWS

            lColThisWS = 35

            'If last row >= StartRow, copy the range

                Set copyRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow - 1, startCol), ws.Cells(lRowThisWS, lColThisWS)) 'data range

                'copyRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*_QC*"                    'hide QC rows

                copyRng.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"                    'hide blank rows in col C


                If copyRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then      'if there is any visible data left

                    'copy visible range only
                    Set copyRng = copyRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Range(copyRng.Cells(startRow, startCol), copyRng.Cells(lRowThisWS, lColThisWS))

                    copyRng.Copy  'copy values and formats

                    With wsAccess.Cells(lRowAccess + 1, "A")
                        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                        '.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
                    End With
                End If
                'copyRng.AutoFilter Field:=1
                copyRng.AutoFilter Field:=3
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does `copyRng` include an inherent *header row* that would never be blank? If not, you may want to include that for the `If` statement check to work properly. I have come across this before and it's often because my range declarations are a bit off. If you step through the code line-by-line and debug you can probably find the failure. The problem could also be with `getMaxCell(ws.UsedRange)` as the `UsedRange` may be bigger than you think. `UsedRange` has faults at times when trying to find the last **used** cell of a sheet.

Comment: Actually, I’m collecting data from three sheets. If I include the header row, it will copy headers from three different sheets to Master sheet, or am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: you can remove the header again inside the `IF` statement by resetting the `copyRng` (which you already do). Actually, you can just do a simple `Intersect`, like `Intersect(copyRng.Offset(1),copyRng).Copy` to remove the header row.

Comment: see [this](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/) for more information on pitfalls of `.UsedRange`

Comment: I should replace `Usedrange?`

Comment: do what you feel is best for you in your code. I just want to make you aware of the pitfalls of using it. They may or may not apply to your dataset.

Comment: sorry, but i'm confused by what is causing the issue. In the code `startRow = 2` and `Set copyRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow - 1, startCol), ws.Cells(lRowThisWS, lColThisWS)) 'data range` so filter should include the first row, or am I wrong? thanks

Comment: check the values of `lRowThisWS` (more important) and `lColThisWs`. Is the row assigned to `lRowThisWS` completely blank in terms of actual data?

Comment: I've changed `lRowThisWS = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and the values are correct for each sheet. one of the sheets has only the header. I'm still not following what's wrong

Comment: what is `debug.print copyRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count ` when you expect it to be 1?

Comment: if I leave col C blank on all three sheets and `debug.print copyRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count` I get 35 but it should be 31 rows total on all three sheets. Thanks

Comment: wait ... duh! change `copyRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count` to `copyRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).**Rows**.Count`. (remove the `**`). Then your If statement will work. Funny how something so simple can be overlooked!

Comment: When I add .Rows it does let me copy any rows to the Master sheet.  Even when there are rows with data in Col C.  Any idea what else might work? thanks

Comment: Ok, I'm back to using for loops. :)